# Display SUM and LAST_VALUE groups by Year

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Last forum I made question how to display values following max date, but I want to sum some values group by max date unfortunately a single value didn't want follow max date.

Here was my table:

[image: the table]

And my query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(pembelian) AS Buying,
    SUM(penjualan) AS Selling, 
    SUM(penjualan)-SUM(pembelian) AS Benefit, 
    saldo, 
    MAX(tgl_lap) 
FROM laporan GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tgl_lap,'%Y')
```

The results:

[image]

As we saw it, the results does work for some values but a single value (`saldo`) didn't following max date, guys can see the row of 2020 should be '23581800' and 2021 should be '35639800' according table.
So what I have missed?

Comment: Please put the table data and result as text, not a pictures

Comment: You have missed the `sum()` around `saldo`

Comment: @Christian, It should not be `SUM` it should to be last value. @FF.Dantiano, what MySQL version you have?

Comment: @Christian i dont need sum() a saldo, i want to keep it as real values like the table

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev i dont have any idea how to do that :(

Comment: Execute `select version();` to get the version of MySql that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean next query can solve the problem:

```
SELECT Buying, Selling, Benefit, saldo, last_tgl_lap
FROM laporan
JOIN (
  SELECT
    SUM(pembelian) AS Buying,
    SUM(penjualan) AS Selling, 
    SUM(penjualan)-SUM(pembelian) AS Benefit, 
    MAX(tgl_lap) last_tgl_lap
  FROM laporan 
  GROUP BY YEAR(tgl_lap)
) aggregated on aggregated.last_tgl_lap = tgl_lap;
```

Look here the example [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b591628063991b88bdf38f4868e9c827&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

If your MySQL version is 8.0 or greater you can use window function like:

```
SELECT 
    Pembelian AS Buying,
    Penjualan AS Selling,
    Penjualan - Pembelian AS Benefit,
    Saldo,
    LastDate
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(pembelian) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap ASC) AS Pembelian,
    SUM(penjualan) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap ASC) AS Penjualan,
    LAST_VALUE(saldo) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap ASC) AS Saldo,
    LAST_VALUE(tgl_lap) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap ASC) AS LastDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap DESC) AS row_num
  FROM laporan
) tbl
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Fiddle on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f6af98c52065d1a820e9b8cda722c006&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 1):

Because of `MySQL` mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled I think your query is not throwing error even though you have used non aggregated column `saldo` in the select clause.

**Update after Clarification from OP**

Another alternative to use window function `first_value` for `saldo` if you can,

```
select sum(pembelian) as Buying,
       sum(penjualan) as Selling, 
       sum(penjualan)-sum(pembelian) as Benefit, 
       max(saldo) as Saldo,
       max(tgl_lap) as tgl_lap
from
( select id_lap,pembelian,penjualan,tgl_lap,
         first_value(saldo) over 
         (partition by date_format(tgl_lap,'%Y') order by tgl_lap desc) as saldo
   from laporan
) l
group by date_format(tgl_lap,'%Y')
```

Comment: it work but in 2020-12-10 the saldo values should be 23581800 not from of all of the dates

Comment: What do you mean ? what value are you getting ?

Comment: you can see in the first table image above, 2020-12-12 should be 23581800, if use max the saldo will show max of value from all of the date

Comment: Ahh. You are right.. would delete my answer for the moment. Thank you.

Comment: I used `first_value` but you can also use `last_value` and remove `desc` from `order by` clause of the `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is malformed.  You have `saldo` in the `SELECT`, but it is not in the `GROUP BY`.  You should be getting an error.  An MySQL finally conforms to the SQL standard and to other databases in generating an error.

In MySQL 8.0, I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(pembelian) AS Buying, SUM(penjualan) AS Selling, 
       SUM(penjualan)-SUM(pembelian) AS Benefit, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN saldo END) as saldo,
       MAX(tgl_lap) 
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tgl_lap) ORDER BY tgl_lap DESC) as seqnum
      FROM laporan l
     ) l
GROUP BY YEAR(tgl_lap);
```

Note that I replaced `DATE_FORMAT()` with `YEAR()`.  It just seems clearer to me to use the appropriate `date` function when it is available.

In older versions, there is a hack to get the latest `saldo` value in each year:

```
SELECT SUM(pembelian) AS Buying, SUM(penjualan) AS Selling, 
       SUM(penjualan)-SUM(pembelian) AS Benefit, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(saldo ORDER BY tgl_lap DESC), ',', 1) + 0 as saldo,
       MAX(tgl_lap) 
FROM laporan l
GROUP BY YEAR(tgl_lap);
```

This concatenates the `saldo` values into a string and then takes the first element.  The only caveat is that the default internal length is about 1,000 characters for `GROUP_CONCAT()`.